# SQL Server: Buffer page read/writes per second reported high

Tags: sql-server

Our SQL Server is reporting high buffer page read/writes per second. Several documentation sources suggest these stats should be less than 90 per second. Our database server is reporting:

```
counter          cntr_value  cntr_type
--------------------------------------
Page reads/sec   4023952     272696576
Page writes/sec  6483243     272696576
```

I'm not certain that I'm reading those stats correctly, but it appears they're much higher than 90. Despite these high read/write numbers, the buffer cache hit ratio is 100%.

Several sources mention that low memory issues can lead to this high read/write buffer page problem.  The server has 96GB of memory and is only using 45GB, 50GB is free. Maximum instance memory is configured for 92GB, although this is standard version of SQL Server and I believe that's limited to 64GB of memory.

The Server is virtualized via KVM on CentOS linux. The virtual guest is running Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2012, has 8 virtual CPU's and 96GB of memory. The only other virtual guest on this virtual host is a SQL Server test server which also has 8 virtual CPUs and 24GB of memory in use. The Test system is idle.

The SQL Server has a single instance, with three databases. One database is 50GB, the second 10GB, and the third 2.5GB. The database server has around 20-30 concurrent users and is running a financial system, mostly small single record changes, with periodic medium sized batch transactions.

**UPDATE**
I found that these counters are cumulative. In other words, you need to take note of the counter at two periods with a known time difference and then perform the math. Basically, we're rarely going to disk and this is not a problem for us.

Yes, we are experiencing some performance issues in some areas. Slow response with data querying from the application screens is the most common. However, I don't know that it's a database related problem, it could be something else in the applications stack.

This is a new RDBMS system, recently converted from HPUX/Oracle. My only baseline is from that Oracle system. Unfortunately, the HPUX box was an older PA-RISC system that was no where near as powerful and with less/slower resources.

In many areas (Copying databases, backups, etc.) the SQL server system is much faster. I'm starting to think the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Is there actually a performance problem? Do you have a baseline to compare to? Some paper saying that some number is a threshold to be concerned about is usually hogwash - how could that paper possibly know what is *normal* for *your* system?

Comment: Agreed with Aaron. Unless extremely egregious, counters without a point if reference (I.e. Baseline) is hard to work with.